# Inline objects becomes block while using some (hidden-xs) classes in twitter-bootstrap-3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[BOOTPLY HERE](http://www.bootply.com/103025)

I try to make some buttons text hidden to make them smaller for xs screen size.

```
<button class="btn navbar-btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-font"></i>
    <span class="hidden-xs">Add Text</span>
</button>
```

There is no problem with element hiding but now `span` makes my button 2 rows. Is there any way to  solve this problem.

Or is there any better approach to hide button texts in bootstrap?

[image]

For the ones who still has the same problem

**If you are using bootstrap 3:**
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

```
<button class="btn navbar-btn btn-primary">
    <i class="icon-picture"></i>
    <span class="visible-sm-inline visible-md-inline visible-lg-inline">Add Image</span>
</button>
```

**If you are using bootstrap 4:**
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#responsive-utilities

```
<button class="btn navbar-btn btn-primary">
    <i class="icon-picture"></i>
    <span class="hidden-xs-down">Add Image</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Try post jsFiddle? :)

Comment: Is it happening when you resize the screen? Coz XS SCREEN img is looking good.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since Bootstrap 3 uses..

```
.hidden-xs {
    display: block !important;
}
```

You need to do this..

```
.navbar-btn .hidden-xs {
    display: inline-block !important;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.navbar-btn .hidden-xs {
  display: none!important;
 }
}
```

to override the `block` display of the `xs` span.

http://bootply.com/103026

Comment: But this time `hidden-xs` is not hiding its content anymore.

Comment: Oh yeah.. you also need a media query. I updated my answer and Bootply: http://bootply.com/103026

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to go around this BS3 issue is to simply add a custom media query to your css. Simply hide the span since I'm sure there might be other elements you wouldn't want to `display:block`

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
    .navbar-btn span,
    .other-element {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the minified css below after Bootstrap 3 and use it like

```
<div class="hidden-xs inline-block"></div>
```

It only affects the .visible-xx / .hidden-xx elements which also have the .inline-block class

```
.inline-block{display:inline-block;}
.inline-block.visible-xs{display:none!important;}@media(max-width:767px){.inline-block.visible-xs{display:inline-block!important;}
}@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){.inline-block.visible-xs.visible-sm{display:inline-block!important;}
}@media(min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px){.inline-block.visible-xs.visible-md{display:inline-block!important;}
}@media(min-width:1200px){.inline-block.visible-xs.visible-lg{display:inline-block!important;}
}.inline-block.visible-sm{display:none!important;}@media(max-width:767px){.inline-block.visible-sm.visible-xs{display:inline-block!important;}
}@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){.inline-block.visible-sm{display:inline-block!important;}
}@media(min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px){.inline-block.visible-sm.visible-md{display:inline-block!important;}
}@media(min-width:1200px){.inline-block.visible-sm.visible-lg{display:inline-block!important;}
}.inline-block.visible-md{display:none!important;}@media(max-width:767px){.inline-block.visible-md.visible-xs{display:inline-block!important;}
}@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){.inline-block.visible-md.visible-sm{display:inline-block!important;}
}@media(min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px){.inline-block.visible-md{display:inline-block!important;}
}@media(min-width:1200px){.inline-block.visible-md.visible-lg{display:inline-block!important;}
}.inline-block.visible-lg{display:none!important;}@media(max-width:767px){.inline-block.visible-lg.visible-xs{display:inline-block!important;}
}@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){.inline-block.visible-lg.visible-sm{display:inline-block!important;}
}@media(min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px){.inline-block.visible-lg.visible-md{display:inline-block!important;}
}@media(min-width:1200px){.inline-block.visible-lg{display:inline-block!important;}
}.inline-block.hidden-xs{display:inline-block!important;}@media(max-width:767px){.inline-block.hidden-xs{display:none!important;}
}@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){.inline-block.hidden-xs.hidden-sm{display:none!important;}
}@media(min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px){.inline-block.hidden-xs.hidden-md{display:none!important;}
}@media(min-width:1200px){.inline-block.hidden-xs.hidden-lg{display:none!important;}
}.inline-block.hidden-sm{display:inline-block!important;}@media(max-width:767px){.inline-block.hidden-sm.hidden-xs{display:none!important;}
}@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){.inline-block.hidden-sm{display:none!important;}
}@media(min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px){.inline-block.hidden-sm.hidden-md{display:none!important;}
}@media(min-width:1200px){.inline-block.hidden-sm.hidden-lg{display:none!important;}
}.inline-block.hidden-md{display:inline-block!important;}@media(max-width:767px){.inline-block.hidden-md.hidden-xs{display:none!important;}
}@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){.inline-block.hidden-md.hidden-sm{display:none!important;}
}@media(min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px){.inline-block.hidden-md{display:none!important;}
}@media(min-width:1200px){.inline-block.hidden-md.hidden-lg{display:none!important;}
}.inline-block.hidden-lg{display:inline-block!important;}@media(max-width:767px){.inline-block.hidden-lg.hidden-xs{display:none!important;}
}@media(min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){.inline-block.hidden-lg.hidden-sm{display:none!important;}
}@media(min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px){.inline-block.hidden-lg.hidden-md{display:none!important;}
}@media(min-width:1200px){.inline-block.hidden-lg{display:none!important;}}
```